# A nonzero holomorphic parallel section never vanishes

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I'm reading a vanishing theorem from Kobayashis' differential geometry of complex bundles and I'm stuck with an argument.

Let $E\rightarrow M$ a holomorphic vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold.

At some point of the proof he says that a nonzero holomorphic section $\xi$ that is parallel (wrt Chern connection) never vanishes. Why is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to the holomorphic setup but holds for parallel sections of any linear connection. It needs the assumption that $M$ is connected, though. Suppose that $\nabla s=0$ and that $x_0\in M$ is such that $s(x_0)=0$. Then for any point $x\in M$, connectedness implies that there is a smooth curve in $M$ that connects $x_0$ to $x$ and since $\nabla s=0$, $s(x)$ has to be obtained by parallely transporting $s(x_0)$ to $x$ along $c$. But parallel transport is a linear map, so the parallel transport of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! so, is as simple as check the definition of parallelism...

Comment: Alternatively the norm squared of a parallel section is constant (by differentiation), so if it is zero at one point it is zero everywhere.